# How to find $\int \frac {dx}{(x-1)^2\sqrt{x^2+6x}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

find the integral of $f(x)=\frac1{(x-1)^2\sqrt{x^2+6x}}$

my attempt =
$(x-1)=a$,     $a=x+1$  so the integral'd be

$\int \frac {dx}{(x-1)^2\sqrt{x^2+6x}}=\int\frac{da}{a^2\sqrt{a^2+8a+7}} $

lets say  $\sqrt{a^2+8a+7}=(a+1)t$

so $a=\frac{7-t}{t-1}$ and $da=\frac{-6dt}{(t-1)^2}$

$\int\frac{da}{a^2\sqrt{a^2+8a+7}}=\int\frac{\frac{-6dt}{(t-1)^2}}{(\frac{7-t}{t-1})^2\frac{6t}{t-1}}=-\int\frac{(t-1)dt}{(7-t)^2t}$

$\frac{(t-1)}{(7-t)^2t}=\frac{A}{t}+\frac{B}{7-t}+\frac{C}{(7-t)^2}$

then $A=B=\frac{-1}{7}$ and $C=6$

$-\int\frac{(t-1)dt}{(7-t)^2t}=\frac{1}{7}\int\frac{dt}{t}+\frac{1}{7}\int\frac{dt}{7-t}-6\int\frac{dt}{(7-t)^2}=\frac{ln|t|}{7}-\frac{ln|7-t|}{7}+6\frac{1}{7-t}$

finally we      substitute      $t=\frac{7+a}{a+1}$ and a=x+1

is my solution attempt correct? if it is, is there another simpler way to solve?

edit: a should equal to x-1 and x =a+1

Comment: You have written $x-1=a$ and $a=x+1$ as if they were the same thing, but they're not. Also, you can always check whether an answer is correct by differentiating the answer and seeing whether you get back the original integrand.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks. my silly mistake while writing from paper

Comment: He probably meant $x-1=a\iff x=a+1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $$\frac{1}{x-1}=t$$  $\implies$ $$ \frac{dx}{(x-1)^2}=-dt$$ So

$$-I=\int \frac{t \,dt}{\sqrt{7t^2+8t+1}}$$ Put $$ 7t^2+8t+1=z^2$$ $\implies$
$$(7t+4)dt=zdz$$ So

$$ -7I=\int \frac{7t+4-4 \,dt}{\sqrt{7t^2+8t+1}}=\int \frac{7t+4 \,dt}{\sqrt{7t^2+8t+1}}-\int \frac{4 \,dt}{\sqrt{7t^2+8t+1}}$$$$$$ So

$$-7I=z-\int \frac{4 \,dt}{\sqrt{7t^2+8t+1}}=z-\frac{4}{\sqrt{7}}\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(t+\frac{4}{7})^2-(\frac{3}{7})^2}}$$ So

$$-7I=\sqrt{7t^2+8t+1}-\frac{4}{\sqrt{7}}Ln\left|(t+\frac{4}{7})+\sqrt{(t+\frac{4}{7})^2-(\frac{3}{7})^2}\right|+Const$$ Finally Replace $t=\frac{1}{x-1}$

Comment: thanks. shouldnt it be $\frac{-I}{7}$? and can you explain last Ln|...| please. I did $t+\frac{4}{7}=m$, and $m=\frac{3}{2}coshc$ and so found $cosh^{-1}(\frac{2(t+\frac{4}{7})}{3})$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle a=\frac{7-t^2}{t^2-1}$ instead of $\displaystyle a=\frac{7-t}{t-1} $ ??

Doing that and simplifying we get, $\displaystyle -\frac{12 t}{\left(t^2-1\right)^2}$ and integrating, we get
$$-2 \left(-\frac{3 t}{7 \left(t^2-7\right)}+\frac{2 \log \left(\sqrt{7}-t\right)}{7 \sqrt{7}}-\frac{2 \log \left(t+\sqrt{7}\right)}{7 \sqrt{7}}\right)$$

Putting back $x$ and simplifying we get
$$\frac{-7 \sqrt{x (x+6)}-4 \sqrt{7} (x-1) \log \left(\sqrt{7}-\frac{\sqrt{x (x+6)}}{x}\right)+4 \sqrt{7} (x-1) \log \left(\frac{\sqrt{7} x+\sqrt{x (x+6)}}{x}\right)}{49 (x-1)}$$

[Differentiating it and simplifying](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Simplify%5BD%5B%20%20%201/%2849%20%28-1%20%2b%20x%29%29%20%28-7%20Sqrt%5Bx%20%286%20%2b%20x%29%5D%20%2b%20%20%20%20%20%20%204%20Sqrt%5B7%5D%20%28-1%20%2b%20x%29%20Log%5B%28Sqrt%5B7%5D%20x%20%2b%20Sqrt%5Bx%20%286%20%2b%20x%29%5D%29/x%5D%20-%20%20%20%20%20%20%204%20Sqrt%5B7%5D%20%28-1%20%2b%20x%29%20Log%5BSqrt%5B7%5D%20-%20Sqrt%5Bx%20%286%20%2b%20x%29%5D/x%5D%29,%20x%5D%5D) we get, your original function.